# Fullcalendar de la V4 no me reconoce la funcion refetchEvent()

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Este es mi código con ajax. Ingresa el dato en la base de datos sin problema. Pero no me refresca los eventos del [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/)

¿Por qué?

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax/ajax.plantilla.php?accion=' + accion,
            data: objEvento,
            success: function(msg) {
                console.log(msg);
                if (msg) {


                    calendar.refetchEvents();

                    $('#modalReserva').modal('toggle');


                }
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("hay un error..");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: paseandome un rato por "docs" de fullcalendar, refetchevents fue removido en la versión 4, al parecer debes obtener la fuente de datos del evento (sourceEvent) y a ese aplicarle el `fetch` https://fullcalendar.io/docs/EventSource-refetch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según la documentación oficial: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-display

> "Rerenders all events on the calendar."

Se vincula con este código:

```
calendar.rerenderEvents()
```

Sin embargo, de acuerdo a los cambios en su API: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v3

Ahora, en tu código, esto podría funcionar:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax/ajax.plantilla.php?accion=' + accion,
        data: objEvento,
        success: function(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
            if (msg) {


               var eventSource = calendar.getEventSourceById('a');
               eventSource.refetch();

                $('#modalReserva').modal('toggle');


            }
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("hay un error..");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Ya lo he intentado con esa funcion anteriormente pero sigo sin obtener que se actualicen los eventos. Tengo que recargar toda la la pagina para que me muestro el registro una vez ingresados

Comment: ¿Ya viste `calendar.addEvent( event [, source ] )` ? La demoa está aquí: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-addEvent-demo

Answer (score 0):

Si amigo esa he estado usando y si actualiza sin problemas el fullcalendar. Solo para hacer el registro no hay problema. El problema es cuando voy a borrae el evento. Y como uso el ID para borrar que viene desde la base de datos no me lo muestra debido a que el fullcalendar no se refresca.

$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'ajax/ajax.plantilla.php?accion=' + accion,
                data: objEvento,
                success: function(msg) {
                    console.log(msg);
                    if (msg) {

```
                    calendar.rerenderEvents()
                    calendar.addEvent({
                        id: $("#txtId").val(),
                        title: $("#txtNombre").val(),
                        start: $("#txtFechaInicio").val(),
                        end: $("#txtFechaFinal").val(),
                        resourceId: $("#txtHabitacion").val(),

                        extendedProps: {
                            habitacion: $("#txtHabitacion").val(),
                        },
                    })

                    $('#modalReserva').modal('toggle');


                }
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("hay un error..");
            }
        });
    }
```